# Draw the reflex effect for cairo text

Tags: c, cairo

[image]

For draw the reflex effect we have to draw the image with flip y.
To draw with transparency, we have to use the mask method.

Is any method to make this for font glyphs directly?

To draw verticaly flip text I use:

```
/* normal text */
cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0, 1, 0); /* green */
cairo_move_to (cr, x, y);
cairo_show_text (cr, TEXT);

/* vertically flipped text */
cairo_matrix_t font_matrix;

cairo_get_font_matrix (cr, &font_matrix);
font_matrix.xx = TEXT_SIZE;
font_matrix.yy = -TEXT_SIZE;
font_matrix.y0 = 5;
cairo_set_font_matrix (cr, &font_matrix);
cairo_move_to (cr, x, y)
cairo_show_text (cr, TEXT);
```

and I need to draw with a gradient, so can reach the reflex effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh....

I need to create a similar surface with CAIRO_OPERATOR_CLEAR.
Something like that:

```
cairo_surface_t *mask;
cairo_pattern_t *pattern;
cairo_matrix_t font_matrix;
cairo_t *cr2;

mask = cairo_surface_create_similar (cairo_get_group_target (cr),
                                     CAIRO_CONTENT_ALPHA,
                                     width, height);
cr2 = cairo_create (mask);
cairo_surface_destroy (mask);

cairo_save (cr2); {
cairo_set_operator (cr2, CAIRO_OPERATOR_CLEAR);
cairo_paint (cr2);
} cairo_restore (cr2);

pattern = cairo_pattern_create_linear (0, height - (extents.height + extents.y_bearing), 0, font_extents.ascent);
cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (pattern, 0.00, 1, 1, 1, 0);
cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (pattern, 0.25, 1, 1, 1, 0.25);
cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (pattern, 0.50, 1, 1, 1, 0.5);
cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (pattern, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0.75);
cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba (pattern, 1.00, 1, 1, 1, 1);
cairo_set_source (cr2, pattern);
cairo_pattern_destroy (pattern);

cairo_set_font_face (cr2, font_face);

cairo_set_font_size (cr2, TEXT_SIZE);

cairo_get_font_matrix (cr, &font_matrix);
font_matrix.xx = TEXT_SIZE;
font_matrix.yy = -TEXT_SIZE;
font_matrix.y0 = 5;
cairo_set_font_matrix (cr, &font_matrix);
cairo_move_to (cr, x, y)
cairo_show_text (cr, TEXT);

cairo_mask_surface (cr, cairo_get_target (cr2), 0, 0);
cairo_destroy (cr2);
```